# $\operatorname {Var}[e^{Z-X}]$ where $X ~ \operatorname{Exp}(1)$ and $P(Z = 1) = P(Z = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: probability

Studying for exams I'm doing old exam sets and am stuck on this single problem.

$X \sim \text{Exp}(1)$, that is the exponential distribution with $\lambda = 1$.

$P[Z = 1] = P[Z = -1] = \frac{1}{2}$

X and Z independent.

I'm supposed to find $\operatorname {Var}[e^{Z-X}]$ and I don't know how to tackle this with introductory probability theory.

Comment: Independence???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,
$$E\left[e^{Z-X}\right]=E\left[e^{-X}\right]\frac{e^{1}+e^{-1}}{2}=$$
$$=E\left[e^{-X}\right]\cosh(1).$$

and

$$E\left[e^{-X}\right]=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-2x}\ dx=\frac12.$$

Second,
$$E\left[\left(e^{Z-X}\right)^2\right]=E\left[e^{2Z-2X}\right]=E\left[e^{-2X}\right]\frac{e^{2}+e^{-2}}{2}=$$
$$=E\left[e^{-2X}\right]\cosh(2).$$
and

$$E\left[e^{-2X}\right]=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-3x}\ dx=\frac1{3}.$$

Finally,

$$\operatorname{Var}\left(e^{Z-X}\right)=E\left[\left(e^{Z-X}\right)^2\right]-E^2\left[e^{Z-X}\right]=$$
$$=\frac1{3}\cosh(2)-\frac14\cosh^2(1).$$